# How do I avoid creating files that vim says have been modified, but when I recover them I find that the recovered and original are identical?

Tags: original-vim

I often open a file in vim that is marked as "modified", but when I go through the process of recovering and diffing it with the original I find that the files are identical.  I assume that I am doing something wrong, something that makes vim think the original and swap files differ, or vim would not identify them as modified.  Has anyone else had this experience and identified some practice that causes this to happen?  If so, what has caused this for you?

Clarifications based on questions asked of me:

These files could be new, but usually are not.

And vim indicates that the file is modified when I open it.  Before fully opening the file it gives me quite a bit of information about the file, including that it has been modified.  There are a few options as to how to proceed.

I am talking about files that are not open elsewhere, I get a similar response from vim, but it indicates that the file is open elsewhere, so I just find the new file

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify a couple things. 1) You say you are _creating_ files...this is happening with files that didn't exist before starting Vim? 2) How is Vim indicating that a file was modified?

Comment: Are you opening files that are also open in another vim instance? Or stopping vim without quitting it properly (_e.g._, using `kill` or shutting down)?

Comment: @BLayer I have made clarifications to my questions based on your comment.  I don't have enough reputation to up vote your comment, so thanks.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, I have added clarifications to my question based on your comments but I don't have the reputation yet to upvote them, so thanks!  Also, it may be that these are files that have been killed from outside, I will watch to see if that is it.  I try not to do that, but sometimes it does happen.  Again, thanks!